# Local server fails to start (Local FlyWhell)

Tags: wordpress, localserver

Local flywheel is not starting properly because it cannot open port 443 ("Heads-up!, Local's routing is having trouble starting" is the message).

I used netstats -o and nothing was using port 443.

The log from FlyWheel says:
bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (10013: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions)

Answer (score 0):

try this
run CMD as admin
type **net stop http**

Answer (score -1):

There is an easy solution...
Preferences> Advanced> Router Mode > Localhost

It will work then.
You can watch [this](https://youtu.be/Q0mH7M1tItM) too

[Heads up! Local's router is having trouble starting - Solved](https://youtu.be/Q0mH7M1tItM)